# Deleted question and post count

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I just found a question of mine was deleted. No big deal, no one answered anyway, that was a more or less a niche question.

The main point is, that question was infested by a troll (or a bot) who filled the comment with useless phrases and clearly wrong statements. That was or a troll or someone aiming to mere post count for ego inflating.

I reported that but it seems the mods did not agree and left it as such.

The question was also downvoted, I am sure by the same questionable user so fewer people were attracted by the question and the field was free for them.

Now the question is: since the question is deleted, the post/comment count (or whatever reward if exists) of people who posted in a deleted question is decreased also?

That would be a good troll/disruptive users deterrent.

EDIT: I think someone would say my question was deleted because it was bad or similar. Very well, if this is true, I was punished by troll infestation. My question is still valid.

Comment: Comment count is not important nor relevant in this site. But those comments are gone anyway, since it appears that's what are asking about...

Comment: do you have a screenshot/link of what you are talking about? also comments dont give any rewards/rep

Answer (score 2):

If someone is truly being rude, moderators will act on that to delete their comments and provide warnings and eventual suspensions to deter this behavior. There isn't really any reward for posting comments. In fact, there is a 50-reputation threshold you have to pass in order to be able to post comments in order to prevent spam and trolling.

In this case, I don't see any evidence of trolling. For posterity, here are all the comments that were on your question:

[image]

I see someone being polite and really making an effort to help you out with what they thought was relevant information. I have no idea why you would think this person was a "bot" or "troll", and your responses to them were completely inappropriate. Acting like this towards people trying to help you will make it less likely that folks will want to aid you in the future.

Comment: What I find really strange is that their flag doesn't contain a single occurrence of "bot" or "troll" - in fact, their flag was far more sweet than the salt we see in this meta question, all things considered. I can see why comments that seem helpful on the surface just end up being noise when they're wrong or otherwise misunderstanding of the problem. Until the last part where the asker snaps, that is.

Comment: Weren't there any offers for *move this discussion to chat*?

Comment: @Brad Larson "I see someone being polite and really making an effort" Good, because this is the exact strategy trolls use. Moderators generally are trained to recognize insults or clickbait links but not technical details (I do not know here) so trolls avoid that. On the surface, they are polite. I think in fact my answers are the opposite of inappropriate. But it should not require a great technical expertise to recognize that if my post has a big font title "I can not get the COM port" and the comment is "well check the COM ports" this is not helpful, nor does want to be.

Comment: @BoltClock At least you can see the comments are wrong and change target. I honestly do not know how malicious they were, for sure they were useless and careless. After so many comments and a denied flag I felt not having anything to lose, so the "snap". I am good they did not reap points for noise.